# Reuse of DynamoDB table

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

Coming from an SQL background, it's easy to fall into a SQL pattern and mindset when designing NOSQL databases like DynamoDB. However, there are many best practices that rely on merging different kinds of data with different schemas in the same table. This can be very efficient to query for related data, in lieu of SQL joins.

However, if I have two distinct types of data with different schemas, and which are never queried together, since the introduction of on demand pricing for DynamoDB, is there any reason to merge data of different types into one table simply to keep the number of tables down? Prior to on demand, you had to pay for the capacity units per hour, so limiting the number of tables was reasonable. But with on demand, is there any reason not to create 100 tables if you have 100 unrelated data schemas?

Answer (score 1):

I would say that the answer is "**no, but**":

On-demand pricing is significantly more expensive than provisioned pricing. So unless you're just starting out with DynamoDB with a low volume of requests, or have extremely fluctuating demand you are unlikely to use just on-demand pricing. Amazon have an interesting blog post titled [Amazon DynamoDB auto scaling: Performance and cost optimization at any scale](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/amazon-dynamodb-auto-scaling-performance-and-cost-optimization-at-any-scale/), where they explain how you can reserve some capacity for a year, then automatically reserve capacity for 15 minute intervals (so-called *autoscaling*), and use on-demand pricing just to demand exceeding those. In such a setup, the cheapest prices are the long-term (yearly, and even 3 year) reservations. And having two separate tables may complicate that reservation.

The benefit of having one table would be especially pronounced if your application's usage of the two different tables fluctuates up and down over the day. The sum of the two demands will usually be flatter than each of the two demands, allowing the cheaper capacity to be used more and on-demand to be used less.

The reason why I answered "no, but" and not "yes" is that it's not clear how much these effects are important in real applications, and how much can you save - in practice - by using one instead of two tables. If the number of tables is not two but rather ten, or the number of tables changes over the evolution of the application, maybe the saving can be even greater.

Comment: Great answer, thanks. Did not think about reserved capacity. Thing is, a couple of years ago when I was new to DynamoDB I made all the classic mistakes of pretending it was SQL, and setup a service with 40 something tables. In the next project I knew better and used more sensible NOSQL modelling techniques, storing related data together and re-using GSIs for multiple purposes etc. However, I now feel I've been taking it too far; the problem is as always to maintain a good balance between complexity, efficiency and cost. Having to deal with complex union schemas is not always fun.